# Blender using only 2-3% of GPU

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

During final cycles rendering blender using only 2-3% of GPU and 20-70% of CPU. How to change it?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This doesn't mean anything is wrong, the resource usage behavior can change easily based on the scene.  Is it taking a really long time, or doing something else that leads you to believe something isn't right?

Comment: @Kirbinator I noticed that during render view (shift+z), blender using ~25% of GPU.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem with my 1080ti. It might be the scene complexity as pointed out, but only getting 4% of its full capacity seems weird. Anyone has another reason this might be happening?